# PHP 5.3 Download CSV

Tags: php, cakephp, cross-browser, mime-types, cakephp-2.3

When a user clicks a button it's going to download a csv file.  It works in IE9 and Chrome, but not Firefox.  In Firefox 20, the content-type is not being set so it's downloading as a Firefox HTML Document.

```
       $filename = 'exportedLogs.csv';

        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .$filename);
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Pragma: public");

        $csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        $header_row = array('id', 'project', 'customer', 'time spent');

        fputcsv($csv_file, $header_row);
        foreach ($logs as $log) {
            $log = array(
                $log['Log']['id'],
                $log['Log']['project_id'],
                $log['Log']['customer_id'],
                $log['Log']['time_spent']
            );
            fputcsv($csv_file, $log);
        }
        fclose($csv_file);
```

Comment: Did you try with `Content-Type` (note the capital T)?

Comment: Yes, I also tried adding charset=UTF-8 in the Content-type.

Comment: maybe one more header option would help. See http://davidwalsh.name/php-force-download

Comment: I tried the application/force-download and that didn't work either.

Comment: Based on the tags you added to your question, you're using CakePHP. What version of CakePHP are you using? And **where** did you put this code?

Comment: 2.3 and in the controller.

Comment: @Uby FYI, the standard dictates that header field names [are not case-sensitive](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html). Granted, that doesn't necessarily mean every client will obey that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the reason the header wasn't changing was because of cakePhp.  For anybody else having this issue, you must do two things:

1. Add 'csv' to Router::parseExtensions('csv');
2. Add a '.csv' to the action in the form

@ThaJeztah provided a link that may be helpful to others.  It's for json/xml, but the principals can be used for csv too.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#json-and-xml-views

Comment: The official way in CakePHP 2.x to set content type and response headers, is via the Response Object see the documentation here [Dealing with content types](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#dealing-with-content-types)

Comment: Thanks, I changed it.  I am also working on moving it into the App/Lib directory.

Comment: This may be worth reading as well, it's about JSON and XML, but you may use the same logic for CSV [JSON and XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#json-and-xml-views)

Comment: @thaJeztah - Thanks for your help.  The reason the header wasn't being changed was because I didn't have 'csv' enabled in parseExtensions, and I also added a .csv extension to the form action.  I will update my answer above.